# Problems with external harddrive (USB 2.0)

Tags: 14.04, usb, hard-drive, files, performance

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. LTS on a Compaq Presario CQ 60.

After having a few problems, I managed it to run more or less stable (freaking Nvidia problems are more or less resolved by using GNOME Flashback instead of Unity).

I copied about 40 GB of Music and 15 GB of Pictures etc. on a external hard drive (2.0) - backing it up (still using vista) worked fine and acceptably fast. So the laptop definitely has 2.0 USB ports and I am using the correct cable.

However: Trying to copy the files back to the laptop seems to be a massive problem.
Firstly, it is really slow. Second, it keeps crashing, giving me the following message:

```
Error while copying "filename" - Error splicing file: input/output error
```

Then the hard drive comes up again (opens in a new window) as if it loses connection and then get's recognized again.

I can skip the file, but then it still keeps going on with about 2-3 MB/sec.

I am fairly new to Ubuntu - but this should work better, right?

Comment: This would indicate: 1. the file system is corrupted, in which case you could check it with fsck or just reformat it 2. the hard drive is failing and you should look into backing up your data and getting a new hdd. 3. a driver issue (but I doubt it..)

Comment: On my second laptop (win 7) the harddrive works just fine - copyying files with 17-20 MB/sec.

Coopying the files to win pc at the moment (to avoid loosing anything), will run chkdsk after and let u know ... thanks.

But ... if it's running fine on win and slow on ubuntu, it must be s.th. correlated to the OS, or am I mistaken?

Comment: to make sure it is not the harddrive, I just tried it with a usb stick - same problem! ... any suggestions? missing drivers?

Comment: Always the same problem ... usb connection is being dropped in mid transfer

Comment: Hate to add: same problem. This is not an isolated incident. Happens when transferring large volumes of data. I had to resort to burning on DVD. Ridiculous. Should file a bug. I'm on Kubuntu 14.04. But should be the same underlying services.